# Keras model not training properly

Tags: python, keras

Keras model's validation accuracy is not changing, and when I try to run the model it's just outputting same messy numbers. As input I'm giving it flatten 5x4 array of bounding boxes, and the output are keypresses (W,A,S,D).
I'm using it to avoid detected objects for autopilot.
I tried changing activation, layers in model, learning rate and so on, but nothing helped.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Input
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

data = np.load("training_data/data.npz",allow_pickle=True)

X = data['arr_2']
X = keras.utils.normalize(X,axis=1)

Y = data['arr_1']

# Creating model for object processing
model2 = Sequential()

# Model for object processing
# Inputs
model2.add(Input(shape=(20)))
# Hidden layer
model2.add(Dense(16,activation="relu"))
# Outputs
model2.add(Dense(4,activation="softmax"))

model2.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
optimizer="adam",
metrics=['accuracy'])

model2.fit(X,Y,batch_size=256, epochs=20, validation_split=0.1)
```

Comment: Your loss is incorrect, it should be a categorical loss depending on the labels.

Comment: Still same, even if i also changed activation to sigmoid in output layer.

Comment: It is hard to tell without knowing the details of the dataset, does it contain images or?

Comment: As input I use flatten 5x4 bounding box values and as output are pressed keystrokes WASD.

Comment: This is off-topic and should be posted to the sister site https://datascience.stackexchange.com/